# How to use WMI commands to check if a system is connected to Internet?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my winforms app i need to check if the system is connected to internet.
Currently I am using

```
        try
        {
            Dns.GetHostEntry("www.something.com");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

But this doesn't cut it for me. It takes more than two minutes to start the application if the system is not connected to internet(because of Timeout).
Was wondering if WMI command can be used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wininet.dll instead to solve my problem and it works like a charm.

[Please reference this link for its usage.](http://bhanumadan.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/how-to-check-internet-connection-is.html)

Thanks guys for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I use This Class For Check Internet Connect
if User connect with Dsl Modem , below code Can't Sense Internet Connect

```
NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

But This Class Can Solve This ,

```
class InternetConnectionChecker
{
    private bool _connectingFlag = false;
    private Thread _th;

    #region Ping Google To Test Connect Or Disconnect
    private string Ping()
    {
        try
        {
            const string remoteMachineNameOrIP = "173.194.78.104";
            var ping = new Ping();
            var reply = ping.Send(remoteMachineNameOrIP, 5);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(reply.Status.ToString());
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Connecting Cheker Thread
    private void ConCheck()
    {
        var status = Ping();
        _connectingFlag = status == "Success" || status == "TimedOut";
    }

    public bool ConnectingCheker()
    {
        _th = new Thread(ConCheck);
        _th.Start();
        return _connectingFlag;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

For Use //Dont Forget Create Global Instance InternetConnectionChecker

```
    InternetConnectionChecker _connectionChecker = new     InternetConnectionChecker();

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        btn1.Content = _connectionChecker.ConnectingCheker();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about WMI, but there are some .NET Framework classes that can help in the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace. In particular, `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` can tell you if a network connection (not necessarily with internet) is available. In the same namespace, the `Ping` class has several methods for send ping requests that are asynchronous and/or have timeout parameters.